# Type hints for all the classes defined in a module

Tags: python, types, type-hinting, python-typing, code-readability

Let's say I have a module *CustomClasses.py*, which contains 10 classes. I have a method let's say `process()` which can take an object of any of the classes of the `CustomClasses` module.

Method:

```
def process(custom_class_instance):
    some code...
```

Now, for type hints for `custom_class_instance`, I can use `typing.Union` to indicate supported types, but that would definitely take much of the code space (hence reduce readability) and would be some manual work. So is there some other way, with which I can specify that the `custom_class_instance` would be an object of any of the classes in *CustomClasses.py*.

Comment: Make all classes in CustomClasses.py inherit from one common (abstract) base class which you can hint against…?!

Answer (score 0):

As per @deceze's comment on the question, making all classes inherit from a common abstract base class, and using the base class for type-hint works.